# $ 2\log ^2_{4}(|x+1|)+\log_4(|x^2-1|)+\log_{\frac{1}{4}}(|x-1|)=0$

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

Find the sum of solutions to:

$$ 2\log^2_{4}(|x+1|)+\log_4(|x^2-1|)+\log_{\frac{1}{4}}(|x-1|)=0 $$

I'm not sure about what to do with the absolute values, how can I get rid of them?

Should I solve for all various cases depending on the sign of $x+1$ and $x-1$?

Comment: you need to get rid of all the logs by using the change of base formula

Comment: I am sorry, didn't write the first log right, will that be the case now?

Comment: OK, but now use the change of base formula on the last term only and you can simplify and factorize the whole expression...

Comment: the title and body show a totally different story

Comment: @egreg maybe that's not what he was wishing

Comment: @ADG I see no difference; I just removed useless bits.

Comment: It should be squared, but somehow it was reverted back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\log_{1/a}x=-\log_a x
$$
so your equation becomes
$$
2(\log_4|x+1|)^2+\log_4|x+1|+\log_4|x-1|-\log_4|x-1|=0
$$
So
$$
\log_4|x+1|\bigl(2\log_4|x+1|+1)=0
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: Yeah, I used substation the first time when solving, so I had t(2t+1)=0.. and only went on to solve for t=0, somehow I mixed up exponential and log equations so I thought that 2t+1>0 for all t values, but since it's a log it can also be 0, thanks for reminding me :D

Answer (score -1):

I am just adding the solution for you to check after your own computation, the last comment of David contains already the main idea:

So I got $x_1=-2,x_2=0,x_3=-3/2,x_4=-1/2$

bests

Comment: I get the first two solutions, bot not the third and forth :/

Comment: yeah...the first two are already the obvious ones, for the other ones you need to do some transformation and remember that $log(a*b)=log(a)+log(b)$...you can also post your calculations and we check them

Comment: and since there is a bunch of editing going on you better make clear which one is there version you really want to solve, I solved $2\log^2_{4}(|x+1|)+\log_4(|x^2-1|)+\log_{\frac{1}{4}}(|x-1|)==0$

Comment: I edit it myself to be the correct version, it's a squared log, but since I'm a beginner at writing these, I made an error the first time.